# Why is rails not picking up a function defined in .js.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails is not recognising my .js.erb file and simply ignores anything in there.

Relevant snippet in **advanced_search.html.erb**

```
<%= render "advanced_search_orders_form" %>
```

I have another file _advanced_search_orders_form.html.erb, which is displayed correctly with one minor problem.

Relevant snippet in **_advanced_search_orders_form.html.erb**

```
<form id="advancedSearchOrder" name="advancedSearchForm" value="advancedSearch" action="" class=" search line" method="GET" onsubmit="return validateAdvancedSearchForm()" >
```

This validateAdvancedSearchForm() is defined in **_advanced_search_orders_form.js.erb**
but Rails acts as if the function is not even defined. Furthermore even if I just write an alert("Check") in _advanced_search_orders_form.js.erb, it doesn't render. Even the editor (RubyMine) says it can't find definition of this function validateAdvancedSearchForm.

I haven't worked with .js.erb files at all, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong there. Have I defined the filename incorrectly, or do I have to include it etc? Really appreciate a little help here.

Answer (score 0):

validateAdvancedSearchForm() must be placed in a .js file (of .js.coffee, if you use coffee script) inside your assets/javascrips folder, then you can use it from your pages

Comment: So I can't define functions and use them in my .js.erb file?

Comment: In fact, the js.erb files should only be used to render actions (like create, or update). If you want to define a function that takes parameters from ruby data, you should define a function in your assets/javascripts js.coffee or js file, and then invoke this method in your js.erb.

Comment: @Kzu - Care to post an answer of how you would about this. Short answer is perfectly cool. Just give an example illustrating the point.

Comment: but you can also create a js.erb template that will return on a js request with responds_to block

Comment: Btw I can't use a .js file, as I need to validate form and add stuff to @errors which is used throughout the app. Hence the .js.erb file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.js.erb` will not render by default. When you write

```
<%= render "advanced_search_orders_form" %>
```

this will render '_advanced_search_orders_form.html.erb' because this is your default template format.

Try this way:

```
<%= render :file => "advanced_search_orders_form.js.erb" %>
```

Make sure your scripts in that file are in `<script></script>` tag

Comment: Isn't it a js file in essence, why should I have to add <script> </script> explicitly?

Comment: as you are including this inside a 'text/html' response, browser won't know whether this is script or not. browser will execute only when your response format is js.